# HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp, .net-core

Monte una aplicación web en servidor productivo y funcionaba correctamente, hasta el día de hoy donde al ingresar a la URL manda el mensaje del titulo, valide las instalaciones de las runtimes y siguen igual, verifique los permisos del acceso a la carpeta donde esta alojado, y agregue el usuario IIS_IUSRS y di acceso total, el resultado de `dotnet --list-runtimes` es

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

En teoría no he realizado algún cambio dentro del servidor, para que afectara el funcionamiento del sitio.

Añado 3 registros de EventViewer

Error:

```
Unable to locate application dependencies. Ensure that the versions of Microsoft.NetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App targeted by the application are installed.
```

Error:

```
Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
Cannot use file stream for [E:\YMM Web Apps\ScrapSystem\YMMScrapSystem.deps.json]: No such file or directory
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'E:\YMM Web Apps\ScrapSystem\'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'E:\YMM Web Apps\ScrapSystem\YMMScrapSystem.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'E:\YMM Web Apps\ScrapSystem\YMMScrapSystem.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
```

Error:

```
Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/scrap', ErrorCode '0x8000ffff'.
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún log?

Comment: @fredyfx edite la publicación con los 3 errores que me arroja

Comment: Eh vuelto a publicar el sitio, y estoy accediendo de momento

Comment: Edita la pregunta, incluye la forma en que haces el publish, me parece que hay un archivo que se ha omitido, quizás alguien lo eliminó, quizás algún programa le dió de baja.